# Exit after extracting matched lines from log tail

Tags: perl

I'm using a range operator to extract part of a log file, e.g:

```
tail -F logfile | perl -ne 'print if /b/ .. /d/;'
```

Now I am trying to exit the process once the extracted portion has been matched. I tried with:

```
tail -F logfile | perl -ne 'print if /b/ .. (/d/ and exit);'
```

But this doesn't print the final line. How can I make it exit without losing the final line?

Answer (score 4):

There's the obvious solution of repeating the bound check.

```
tail -F logfile | perl -ne'
   next if !(/b/ .. /d/);
   print;
   last if /d/;
'
```

But let's look at alternatives. Check out what `..` returns.

```
$ echo -en 'a\nb\nc\nd\ne\n' | perl -nlE'my $ff = /b/ .. /d/; say "$_: $ff"'
a:
b: 1
c: 2
d: 3E0
e:
```

It uses a string ending in `E0` (scientific notation meaning ×10<sup>0</sup>) to alert the caller that it flopped.

```
tail -F logfile | perl -ne'
   my $ff = /b/ .. /d/;
   print if $ff;
   last if $ff =~ /E0/;
'
```

Using a flip-flop doesn't really help much.

```
tail -F logfile | perl -ne'
   next if !($in ||= /b/);
   print;
   last if /d/;
'
```